# Why destroy pthread_cond_t and pthread_mutex_t?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix

If in a threaded code, I create a `pthread_cond_t c;` condition variable or a mutex `pthread_mutex_t m;` in C, it is advised to destroy them after all the work is done.

Why is it so?

Also why is it utmost necessary to destroy a `cond` variable if it was dynamically initialized using `pthread_cond_init();` function.

To quote from David Butenhof "*Programming with POSIX Threads*"

> "When you dynamically initialize a condition variable, you should
>   destroy the condition variable when you no longer  need it, by calling
>   pthread_cond_destroy.You do not need to destroy a condition variable
>   that was statically initialized using the PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER
>   macro"

Comment: I don't know the implementation, but probably it must be connected to resource handling such as freeing memory, etc.

Comment: Sounds a bit 'off'.  If you need the condvar until 'all threads of my process have been terminated', (ie. during process termination by OS), is is not possible to call pthread_cond_destroy() because there is nothing to call it.  Sure, if you continually create the things and do not destroy them, there will be an issue, but if you only create the condvar once during the life of the app, there is no point in going to extreme lengths to safely destroy it before app close, (at least, in most common OS with process resource management).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

pthread_cond_t and pthread_mutex_t are regarded as resources.

You need to destroy/cleanup/close resources when you are done with them, much like you need to close a file or free memory when you're done with them.
Failure to do so results in a resource leak, and you may run out of theses resources.

Treating these as a resources gives the implementation more freedom on how to implement them, and on some particular implementation, there may be no harm in forgetting to _destroy() them, others may connect the mutex/condition variable to a kernel resource that needs to be cleaned up when you don't need it anymore. The rationale section of [pthread_mutex_init](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/pthread_mutex_init.html) gives some more overview, and the same applies to condition variables

If you initialize a condition variable with PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER, you're supposed to initialize a statically allocated mutex i.e. it is going to live until the application ends, at which point it will be destroyed by the system, presumably that's what the author meant. That applies to mutex/cond variables that is dynamically initialized as well, the system will clean those up as well.

Most resources are automatically cleaned up when an application ends, so whether it's good practice to clean up everything manually or just let the system do it in such case is another discussion.

Comment: "If you initialize a condition variable with PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER, you're supposed to initialize a mutex that's statically allocated, i.e. it is going to live until the application ends" -

How do you figure that? What about a condition variable that's local to a function?

I suspect the real reason is that a condition variable with the default settings, as PTHREAD_COND_INTIALIZER provides, shouldn't require any other resources. If you specify different settings using pthread_cond_init(), however, it might.

Comment: +1, just about perfect answer.  If the alternative to not explicitly destroying some resource is a mess of thread-shutdown code, why bother with all the extra hassle for no gain?

Comment: @davmac - I don't even know why that macro exists.  There is a call for initializing condvars, so why not use it?

Comment: @davmac Because the docs state so, or at least it is implied by "statically allocated". It's not quite obvious if you are supposed to initialize a cond variable on the stack with PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER. But if you do, you would need to pthread_cond_destroy() it. (again, unless it's on the stack of main() and you just let the system clean it up when it's done)

Comment: @MartinJames The rationale section of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/pthread_mutex_init.html tells you the reason for its existence.

Comment: @nos - not necessarily.  If a thread is created that is expected to last for the lifetime of the app, it's reasonable to initialize a cond variable on the stack and never explictly destroy it. Destruction is necessary if you continually create/terminate/destroy threads during the app run.

Comment: @MartinJames Sure, the stack of main() would be similar to the stack of a thread function in such a regard.